# how to set Loading while api call in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For some reason, the `loading` state doesn't change when I'm using this method to **fetch** from the **API**.

How to display "Loading..." while the call is running.

- **async-await** doesn't work either, that's why I'm using this method to fetch.

```jsx
const [product, setProduct] = useState({});
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const productId = 1;

const fetchProduct = () => {
  setLoading(true);
  //here commerce is my api, so i fetched the product details and set it to the product state
  commerce.products.retrieve(productId).then(data => setProduct(data));
  setLoading(false);
}

useEffect(() => {
  fetchProduct();
})

if (loading) {
  return (
    <span>Loading...</span>
  )
}

return (
  <h1>{product.name}</h1>
)
```

Comment: Note that `useEffect()` without second argument (dependencies) will trigger after each render. Make sure to pass an empty array if you only want to fire a request on component mount without making requests thereafter. eg. `useEffect(() => { code... }, [])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the complete state inside the promise result just after retrive the products

```
const fetchProduct = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    commerce.products.retrieve(productId)
        .then(data => {
                       setProduct(data)
                       //HERE
                       setLoading(false);
                       });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there's two way for doing it corresponding of your code.

First, this one:

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

const handleFetch = () => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  someApiCall().then((r) => {
    setIsLoading(false);
  });
};
```

Or

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

const handleFetch = async () => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  await someApiCall();
  setIsLoading(false);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget about `loading`.

You can infer if the data is loading or not from the value of `product`.

```
const Component = () => {
    const [product, setProduct] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getProducts = async () => {
            const data = await commerce.products.retrieve(productId)
            setProduct(data);
        };
        getProducts();
    }, []);

    if (product === null) {
        return <span>Loading...</span>;
    }

    return <h1>{product.name}</h1>;
}
```

If you really wanted to use a separate loading variable then you would have it **default** to `true` and set it to `false` at the same time you give a value to `product`.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't use async await at all
but if you donn't wana use async await then u should use following

```
 const fetchProduct = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    //here commerce is my api, so i fetched the product details and set it to the product state
    commerce.products.retrieve(productId).then(data => {
      setProduct(data);
      setLoading(false);
      }).catch(() => {
        setLoading(false);
     })
    

    }
```

Comment: I suggest removing `setLoading(false)` from the `then()` and `catch()` callbacks, and instead use a [`finally()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally) callback which is triggered on both success and failure.